# scala better syntax for map getOrElse

Tags: scala

is there a better way to write the code below?

```
val t = map.get('type).getOrElse(""); 
if (t != "") "prefix" + t;
```

be interested in inline code something like

```
val t = map.get('type).getOrElse("").????
```

Comment: val t = map.getOrElse("type","") match {case value if value !="" => s"prefix${value}"  case _ => ""}

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Map` has its own `getOrElse` method, so you can just write the following:

```
val t = map.getOrElse('type, "")
```

Which accomplishes the same thing as the definition of `t` in your first example.

---

To address your comment: If you know your map will never contain the empty string as a value, you can use the following to add the `"prefix"`:

```
map.get('type).map("prefix" + _).getOrElse("")
```

Or, if you're using Scala 2.10:

```
map.get('type).fold("")("prefix" + _)
```

If your map *can* have `""` values, this version will behave a little differently than yours, since it will add the prefix to those values. If you want exactly the same behavior as your version in a one-liner, you can write the following:

```
map.get('type).filter(_.nonEmpty).map("prefix" + _).getOrElse("")
```

This probably isn't necessary, though—it sounds like you don't expect to have empty strings in your map.

Comment: Just started learning scala, so this is very useful. What about the second line. Is there a way to combine them?

Comment: @pbaris `val t = map.get('type).map(k => "prefix" + k).getOrElse("")` if I got you right

Comment: compiler says "value nonEmpty is not a member of Any". But what @om-nom-nom suggested works as i expected

Comment: It sounds like your `map` has `Any` as the type of its values, which is likely to get you into trouble. How are you defining it?

Comment: def myfunc(args: (Symbol, Any)*) {...}

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth noting that, in certain cases, you can replace multiple common `.getOrElse` usages with one `.withDefaultValue` call.

```
val map = complexMapCalculation().withDefaultValue("")

val t = map('type)
```

I wouldn't say this is something that should be done every time, but it can be handy.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Scalaz [Zero](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Zero.scala) typeclass so your code would look like below. The unary operator is defined on [OptionW](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/OptionW.scala#L80).

```
val t = ~map.get('type)                 // no prefix
val t = ~map.get('type).map("prefix"+_) // prefix
```

Here's an example session:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val map = Map('type -> "foo")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,java.lang.String] = Map('type -> foo)

scala> ~map.get('type)
res3: java.lang.String = foo

scala> ~map.get('notype)
res4: java.lang.String = ""

scala> ~map.get('type).map("prefix"+_)
res5: java.lang.String = prefixfoo

scala> ~map.get('notype).map("prefix"+_)
res6: java.lang.String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

While reading the book `Play for Scala`, I picked up this code snippet that was defined in a controller, which might be a better syntax for *getOrElse*.

```
def show(ean: Long) = Action { implicit request =>

  Product.findByEan(ean).map { product =>
    Ok(views.html.products.details(product))
  }.getOrElse(NotFound)

}
```

In which, the *Product.findByEan(ean: Long)* was defined like

```
def findByEan(ean: Long) = products.find(_ean == ean)
```

Comment: While this syntax is nice and useful, I am afraid this question is about a different map - you are talking about map collection traversal, while this is about [Map collection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map).

Answer (score 0):

```
 val t = map.getOrElse("type","") match {case value if value !="" => s"prefix${value}" case _ => ""}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.